# How to perform a query search only on documents with one of its Fields matching a specific value in Lucene 7.5.0?

Tags: java, lucene

**Lucene version: 7.5.0**

With two given inputs (*userTitle* & *userQuestion*), I want to perform a search only within the indexed documents whose title matches with *userTitle*, but I am struggling to make this happen.

Below is what I have so far, but this is returning documents with other titles as well.

"title" and "body" are both TextFields.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Query queryTitle = new TermQuery(new Term("title", userTitle));

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
QueryParser qpBody = new QueryParser("body", analyzer);
Query queryBody = qpBody.parse(QueryParser.escape(userQuestion));

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(queryTitle, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .add(queryBody, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
    .build();
```

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you provide an example of a title you are searching for, and a result that you don't want it to match?

Comment: Thanks for your review. I used the generalized names here, but my title includes names of drugs and my body has patients' reviews. User inputs a specific name of the drug (i.e. Advil), and I want to only search reviews within documents whose title is Advil and find documents that have similar reviews as the userQuestion. However, output results show reviews from documents that do not have match the user-given title (Advil).

Comment: did you use any TokenStreams for your text field?